Can we detect the navigation request URL in oauth_webauth package flutter
I have integrated azure ADB2C login in flutter app using oauth_webauth package.

My requirement is to authenticate the user using Microsoft authenticator app after login. So I want to open authenticator app from webview
But when I click on Authenticator app link from OAuthWebScreen, getting error as 'ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME'.

I looked into different approach of fixing the issue.
Found a package webview_flutter which detects the navigation request URL & allows user to intercept the navigation & perform required operation (launching native apps)
With the help of this package, I was able to launch the native apps from webview
Code related to webview_flutter package is displayed

So, I want to know whether similar approach is available in oauth_webauth package where user can detect the navigation request URL.

you can use this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_web_auth
The package supports Android & iOS implementation. You can follow the instructions to add the intent in manifest: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_web_auth#android
